Cardinal power towers
I am not an expert on large cardinals. I could not find any reference (and terminology) for the following question:
We start with
$$\lambda:=\aleph_0 \text{ [tet] } \omega =  \aleph_0 ^ {\aleph_0 ^ {\aleph_0^{\dots}}}= \sup\{\aleph_0, \aleph_0 ^ {\aleph_0},\aleph_0 ^ {\aleph_0 ^ {\aleph_0}},\dots\}.$$ Similarly $$\lambda \text{ [tet] } \omega =  \lambda ^ {\lambda ^ {\lambda^{\dots}}}= \sup\{\lambda, \lambda ^ {\lambda},\lambda ^ {\lambda ^ {\lambda}},\dots\}.$$
I wonder if it is it meaningful to continue in this way transfinitely and can we obtain cardinals as large as we desired, i.e. for any cardinal $\alpha$ can we obtain a cardinal $\kappa$ constructed as above such that $\alpha\leq \kappa$, how? The anwers will be very helpful for some group theoretic problems.

It might be helpful to know that every normal function (i.e., strictly increasing and continuous) has a fixed point (and, in fact, a closed and unbounded set of fixed points).

Transfinite induction, as in over all ordinals? Then I think it is just the von Neumann universe. Cardinal numbers are special ordinals, and so you will go through all of them, by the simple fact that you're using transfinite induction, right?

What you're doing is equivalent to the first couple limit levels of the beth hierarchy (since $\kappa_1^{\kappa_2}=2^{\kappa_2}$ for infinite $\kappa_2\ge \kappa_1$).  We have $\lambda = \beth_\omega$ and the next one is $\beth_{\omega+\omega}.$ (And yes, the beth numbers are unbounded in the cardinals.)

So there is a suitable ordinal $\gamma$ such that $\alpha \leq \beth_\gamma$? Am I correct?

Yes, that's right. $\alpha \le \beth_\alpha$, for example.

Can we choose $\gamma=\omega^\theta$ for some ordinal     $\theta$? It is important for me to know that in which step we obtain the cardinal $\beth_\gamma$ (depending on my groups).

I assume $\omega^\theta$ is ordinal exponentiation. In that case you can take $\gamma = \omega^\alpha$ (also as ordinal exponentiation). In complete generality, you can't hope to do better than $\gamma = \alpha$, due to the existence of "$\beth$-fixed points". If you say any more about your group theory problem maybe someone can help you more. Does it definitely require this level of generalisation? (Also your question is not really about "large cardinals", which has a particular meaning... I have edited to what I think is a more accurate title. Hope that's OK)

Thank you for the nice answer (and any other comments). Group theory part is ok after these discussions.

@AhmetArikan You should tag Izaak instead of me if you're asking them a question... otherwise they won't get alerted.

Oh sorry about that.

@Izaak van Dongen
Could you please make the centence In complete generality, you can't hope to do better than $\gamma=\alpha$, due to the existence of $\beth$-fixed points" clear. Is it compatible with the comment of spaceisdarkgreen?

All it means is that there are cardinals $\alpha$ such that $\beth_\alpha = \alpha$ (so the smallest $\gamma$ such that $\beth_\gamma \ge \alpha$ is $\alpha$ itself). In fact the set of such cardinals is unbounded, as Roy said. In general, this means that finding such a $\gamma$ does not always "simplify" $\alpha$ very much. This is consistent with everything that spaceisdarkgreen has said as far as I can tell (I'm not sure what it would contradict).

I see what you mean, thank you.
